# Choose python environment to launch spyder or jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Python through the latest Anaconda distribution. The default Python version is 3.6 which Anaconda installs in the root environment. However, some of the libraries I need require version 3.5. I created a new environment py3_5 and installed Python 3.5 along with those libraries. I want to choose which version (environment) I want to launch Spyder or Jupyter Notebook, but when I try to launch 3.5 from the Anaconda prompt:

```
C:\Users\me> activate py3_5
(py3_5) C:\Users\me> spyder
```

Spyder launches with Python 3.6. The same thing happens with Jupyter Notebooks. I would prefer the flexibility of choosing the version at the time I launch the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the issue [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/541), everything is explained.

> This is my habit - I frequently make envs and install IPython in them,
>   and register a kernelspec for the env. What I don't do is install the
>   notebook server multiple times.

You can install Ipython (just the kernel, not the notebook) in every environment you have OR change the python path in the kernel.json file.

Comment: Thanks for your help.